# I can not make clicked object for edit selected data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wpf, sql-update

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listView1.SelectedItem;
        string id = drv.Row[0].ToString();
        string Saxeli = textBox4.Text;
        string misamarti = textBox2.Text;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-PR8PO9S;Initial Catalog=tel_operator;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("update abonenti set gvari = @gvari where id =@id", con);

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gvari", textBox1.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saxeli", textBox4.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@misamarti", textBox2.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox3.Text);

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        ShowData();
    }
}
```

WPF C# .NET

Help me when I click on the selected data, the values that are not printed in the text blocks and the update do not work. If I delete the "if" condition and write the ID manually, the update will be performed. I can not select data with a click to update.Thanks

Comment: I am sorry. I don't see any `TextBlocks`. What does `ShowData()` do? 
Have you tried debugging and see what `listView1.SelectedItem` actually is?

Comment: Your code is confusing. You seem to get the id from  `drv.Row[0].ToString();` but then you use `textBox3.Text` for the id parameter of the query. Also, there are unused parameters. Please clarify.